# Angular Firebase Realtime DB issues with promises

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, es6-promise

I have some trouble with angular + firebase Realtime DB

I made a function in my database service like this :

```
  getAllProject() {
    return firebase.database().ref('project').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.val()) {
        const dataObj = snapshot.val();
        return dataObj;
      }
    });
  };
```

which is self explanatory.

Then in my carousel component :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DbService } from '../services/db.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.scss']
})
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {
 

  arrayProject;
    

  constructor(private dbService: DbService) { 

    this.dbService.getAllProject().then((data)=>{
      this.arrayProject = data;
      console.log("this.arrayProject",this.arrayProject);
      //this one is processed in second, result : correct data
    });

   }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log("this.arrayProject 2 : ", this.arrayProject);
    //this one is processed in first result : undefinned

  }
```

I understand that a promise must be resolve before rendering data, but in this case, I call my service during component construction, so why my data is undefinned on ngOnInit() ?

I need this data to be ready before component init, because this data will be used to render: img, text, ect, in my carousel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the getAllProject() returns a Promise and the callback you provided in .then() is called after ngOnInit. move it into ngOnInit

```
 async ngOnInit() {

    this.arrayProject = await this.dbService.getAllProject();
    console.log("this.arrayProject: ", this.arrayProject);
  }
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your response it works.
May you elaborate a little regarding the async ngOnInit ?
Or link me to an article explaining this precisely ?

Comment: Please mark it as accepted if it was helpful. It's a rather big topic but in a nutshell your getAllProject() function returns a response of type Promise which needs to be "unwrapped" to get a value. Since constructor can't be async you unwrap it with .then(callbackFunc) but in this case callbackFunc is executed after ngOnInit so what we did we moved it to the ngOnInit and told it to await for the unwrapped value and only then continue. Async/await is a "syntactic sugar" for Promises. MDN has some good articles https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Thx for your time, marked as accepted.
I'm working with angular typescript for some time now, but I still struggle with these asynchronous operations, I'll check the link.